# Upgraded cygwin on PC and now can't SSH into it from Linux

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I got everything setup perfect and was able to ssh from a Linux box to my PC's cygsrv (Cygwin SSH Server) w/o any problems w/o using a password (BTW, I'm using a DSA key). All .ssh permissions were correct and everything. I even added this line to my .ssh/config on both sides JIC:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

This was working for years. I wanted to install a package to Cygwin and of course it wants to upgrade all the other packages too. I had to shutdown the SSH cygsrv for the upgrade.
Now cygwin is:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.3 PCName 2.4.1(0.293/5/3) 2016-01-24 11:26 x86_64 Cygwin
```

And now I can no longer login w/o a password. Nothing has changed in the .ssh dirs on both sides.

BTW I can auto login from Cygwin to Linux w/o a password. I assume it has something to do with there handling of the DSA hole, making it tighter in security.

Here is the ssh output from Linux.

```
$ ssh -vvv mjhome
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for mjhome
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 108.72.79.8 [108.72.79.8] port 3333.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 4 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 161/320
debug2: bits set: 1024/2048
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
Warning: Permanently added '108.72.79.8' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 1029/2048
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_rsa (0x2b4beaaec650)
debug2: key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_dsa (0x2b4beaaec680)
debug2: key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /export/home/mjobe/.ssh/engdev2_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Again, nothing else has changed from a file perspective (i.e. .ssh/...)

Comment: what is logged on the server side? Which was the key you used to log in? The `id_dsa` is rejected for some reason (will be mentioned in the logs probably), `engdev2_dsa` does not exists on your client. Also you client version is really ancient (4.3p2). I would give a try to update your box to something more recent. RHEL5 is still in support, but the software is really old.

Comment: @Jakuje I'm not in control of the servers and their upgrades... but I hope they upgrade them. There are other machines that are newer and ones with other flavors of linux.
I can just have them spin off VMs of the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

> I even added this line to my .ssh/config on both sides JIC:
>
> ```
> PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
> ```

You should add this to the server config (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and not to the client one. Client config is never read on the server side.

Comment: This has worked before for me. I had a PC with a new verison of cygwin and was unable to get it to auto login to Linux. I added that line to my ~/.ssh/config file in cygwin and it then allowed me to auto login w/o password. By default, cygwin was skipping the dsa when finding keys. The 'skipped' line was in the verbose logs of the client. Now I'm trying to go the other way. I'll try the /etc/sshd_config file in cygwin.